# Add named vector to attribute

Tags: r, igraph

I'm working with igraph, and I would like to assign a named vector to an attribute of my graph's vertex as the following:

```
library(igraph)

test.graph <- graph.famous('bull')
test.vec <- c(0,0,0)
names(test.vec) <- c('a','b','c')
V(test.graph)[1]$test.attr <- test.vec
```

However I get a warning every time, saying:

> Warning message: In vattrs[[name]][index] <- value :   number of items
>   to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

How could I assign that vector to the attribute?

Comment: you have problem `V(test.graph)[1]$test.attr <- test.vec`, the naming a vector part is working fine.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? The warning simply says that you are trying to replace something with length 1 with something of length 3 (test.vec)

Comment: `V(test.graph)[1]` is an object of length `1` while `test.vec` is length `3`. You need to make the two lengths match. E.g. - `test.graph$test.attr <- 1:5` works just fine.

Comment: @paoloeusebi I want to assign a named vector or list to a vertex attribute, so when I will do further calculations/work I could select an item from that vertex attribute list with a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you wanted to assign `test.vec` as an attribute *only to the first vertex*. It doesn't look like it's allowed to set a vector as a vertex attribute, however. But, we may assign a list:

```
V(test.graph)[1]$test.attr <- list(test.vec)
```

or

```
(test.graph <- set.vertex.attribute(test.graph, "test.attr", 
                                    index = 1, list(test.vec)))
# IGRAPH ade745b U--- 5 5 -- Bull
# + attr: name (g/c), test.attr (v/x)
# + edges from ade745b:
# [1] 1--2 1--3 2--3 2--4 3--5
```

Verifying:

```
get.vertex.attribute(z, "test.attr")
# [[1]]
# a b c 
# 0 0 0 
#
# [[2]]
# NULL
#
# [[3]]
# NULL
#
# [[4]]
# NULL
#
# [[5]]
# NULL
```

Comment: Hi Julius I have a problem with sorting the items in igraph. I have posted a question a few days ago but have not got an answer to it.  Could you take a look at: **How to sort duplicated values in igraph plot in R?** Thank you.